# How to count values if option checked is selected in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, flatten, textjoin

I have a spreadsheet where users fill out a form, they have multiple options they can pick by clicking the checkboxes.

The responses sheets looks like this

[image]

I want to filter the results by option, so my main goal is to get the total amount of options selected:
[image]

I've been trying with `COUNTIF` but it's not working because I'm not selecting the specific response

```
=COUNTIF('Form Responses 1'!C2:F4,"*"&$B$1&"*")
```

I'm assuming I need to add a `VLOOKUP` but I'm not sure how to match it with the option

Here's a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191duLXAlTwdZrjTwFOEHwZcq5fqF8HR2tDHlXPV621k/edit#gid=0) to play around with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX({QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B, ",")), "×")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1 'Person'"); 
 {"Total", TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B, ",")), "×")), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", )*1), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, B2:B), ",")))), 1, 1, )))}})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked smoothly, as people and fruit is filled out automatically

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a formula like this:

```
=IFNA(QUERY({$A$2:$A$6, $B$2:$B$6}, "Select 1 where Col2 contains '"&B$9&"' and Col1 = '"&$A10&"' order by Col1 label 1 ''"), 0)
```

This outputs a `1` if the referenced cell contains the specified text, and a `0` otherwise. See the docs for the [Query Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) and the [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) for more information.

Comment: Indeed it works as expected, thanks. I think that can be done by using `ArrayFormula`